# I need a redirected url from given url in curl or any other function using php

Tags: php, laravel, curl, php-curl

I have been trying to get a new url using the current url. When I give the current url my page does not accept it since it is a **https** page and the url I'm trying to load in **iframe** is http. So I tried using the `str_replace()` but then I came to know that after getting this `str_replace`d I get a new http url. So here I need a little help so I tried using the curl but with curl I want to get that redirected url in my iframe src.

```
$tracelink='http://services.gls-netherlands.com/tracking/ttlink.asp?NVRL=32860002&VREF=100436551&CHK=4935';
    $url=parse_url($tracelink);
       if ($url['scheme'] === "https") {

            $link=$tracelink;
      }else{
    $link=str_replace('http', 'https', $tracelink);
     }
 echo '<iframe id="trace_link" src="'.newurl($link).'" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
function newurl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 );
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          $data1=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
          //curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
 }
```

Here I have pasted my code but it does not return the requested src i need.
the requested src looks like this

http://www.gls-info.nl/tracking?USER=HOEKSCHE&NVRL=32860002&VREF=100436551&userType=UNKNOWN&parcel=0&chk=49E92104D06DD0CAC5D683BA2E62EFCD

When I use the `curlinfo_effective_url` it returns the url that i provided but not the new url.